# Accessing constants from within a class

Tags: php, constants

I seem to be having an issue accessing class constants.  I have a config class that defines some constants

```
<?php

class Config
{
   //define my constants
   const DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
}
```

I then have an application class which should use these constants

```
class Application {

    /** @var Config **/
    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->transferFile($this->obtainTextFile());
    }

    private function obtainTextFile() {
        //connect to database and write results to text file

        return $textFile;  //path to the generated file
    }  

    private function transferFile($textFile) {
        //return whether the file was successfully SFTP
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a PHP script file to execute things

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . "/../config/Config.php";
require __DIR__ . "/../classes/Application.php";

$config = new Config();
$app = new Application($config);
$app->execute();
```

Now within my Application Class, I am trying to access the constants.  If this wasnt a class I would generally do something like this

```
$config::DB_HOST
```

Being within a class however, it tells me $config is not defined.  So next logical step would be to do

```
$this->config::DB_HOST
```

But then it tells me Uniform variable syntax is available in PHP 7 only.  So, then I tried

```
self::DB_HOST
```

But this seems to return nothing.  So how can I access these constants?  Do I need to actually create getters within the Config class to access them?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants does not need instance of the class they are part of. Reference it static way, i.e.:

```
$foo = Config::DB_HOST;
```

or

```
$foo = \Some\Namespace\Stuff\Config::DB_HOST;
```

if needed. But that's basically all you need - make the **class** reachable (but not the **object** - it's not needed). See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

> Then I tried self::DB_HOST

This is only useful if you want to reference the const in the same class. Still it's worth understanding the difference between `self::` and `static::`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Really?  So do I need to even pass the Config Object to the Application constructor?

Comment: If you did that for that purpose then no, that's not needed at all. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Perfect.  And if Config is in a different folder to Application, do I need to autoload it?